# Multi-line cells in react-bootstrap-table

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using react-bootstrap-table to display my data in table format. This is an excerpt from my current code:

```
   var table = (
            <BootstrapTable ref="table" data={convertedData} deleteRow={false} striped={true} search={false} pagination={true} hover={true} selectRow={selectRowProp}>
                <TableHeaderColumn columnClassName="col-md-1" dataField="field1" isKey={true}>field1</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn columnClassName="col-md-2" dataField="field2" >field2</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn columnClassName="col-md-2" dataField="field3">field3</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
            {table}
        </div>
    )
},
```

From my css file:

```
.table td.col-md-7 {
  word-wrap: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that cells with a lot of text, gets a scrollbar when what I actually want is to display the text in multiple rows within the cell.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Found an approach that seems ok:

```
function multilineCell(cell, row) {
    return "<textarea class='form-control cell' rows='3'>" + cell +"</textarea>";
}    
[...]
<TableHeaderColumn columnClassName="col-md-4" dataFormat={multilineCell} dataField="summary">Summary</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you @kenneho, Your answer  solved my issue. I want to add one more addition to it. If someone want the data to be non editable, use 'readonly' attribute in textarea tag.